# Main Thread wait for the fiber returning from Concurrent Effect or not?

Tags: multithreading, scala, cats-effect

we are doing IO operations that we want to run in a separate thread and the main thread should not wait for this operation.

```
def seperateThread(action: F[Unit]): F[Unit]
  ConcurrentEffect[F].start(action).void
```

If I will call this function like below

```
for {
    _ <- service.seperateThread(request, languageId, cacheItinerary, slices, pricing)
} yield {}
```

It will do the `seperateThread` operation in different fiber and return F[Unit] immediately or wait for the operation to complete?

Comment: It will start the other operation in its own `Fiber` _(not `Thread`, you don't control `Threads` on **CE**)_, and will continue immediately as soon as the other `Fiber` was properly scheduled. Note you lose the control over the other `Fiber`, you can't cancel or await for it anymore.

Comment: Yeah sorry for using ```Thread``` word.  Yeah, I want to lose control and want to return the response from the main thread asap.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a fiber is a non-blocking operation, so the application flow will right away go to the next instruction.

In order to wait for the operation running in another fiber to complete, you need to invoke the `join` operation on the fiber object. You can't do it in your implementation since you've called `void` thus ignoring returned reference to fiber.

If you change your method like this:

```
def seperateThread[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect: Functor: Sync](action: F[Unit]): F[Fiber[F, Unit]] = ConcurrentEffect[F].start(action)
```

then you'd be able to use reference to created fiber to `join`:

```
for {
    fiber <- ConcurrentEffect[IO].start(IO(println("Hello from another fiber!")))
    // _ <- do some more operations in parallel ...
    result <- fiber.join //here you can access value returned by fiber 
                         //(in your case it's Unit so you can just ignore it).

} yield result
```

Using fiber's `start` directly is not advised in most cases, since it could lead to resource leaks. You should consider using `background` instead which creates `Resource` which will automatically cancel and clean up fiber at the end of processing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your response. I don't want to join the operation. I want my main thread to not wait for this. I think if I will do join then it will wait even the return type unit. Correct me if I am wrong. I think using background is better as you have mentioned about the resource leak.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, if you don't want to wait for the operation, you can just ignore returned fiber reference as you did.